# Apple Developer account and provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to run my app which I build on my `IPAD`

I have a apple developer account which works when I login to site

But when I go to create a provisioning profile link here

```
http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action
```

It shows access denied.

Do I have to have a different account for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must join Apple Developer Program as well at https://developer.apple.com/programs/ to test you app on your hardware.